# When using Marionette.js when should I call vent.trigger('app:show', Controller.layout)?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

Of course the answer is "Use it when you want to show the app".  Ok that is fair enough.  But what about subviews?  I am using Ted's example: https://github.com/t2k/backbone.marionette-RequireJS.  That example only has one controller setup.  I have six controllers which I copied the libraryController in Ted's example.  Each example has the following code:

```
    var _initializeLayout = function() {
       console.log('initialize Start Layout...');
       Controller.layout = new Layout();
       Controller.layout.on("show", function() {
           vent.trigger("startLayout:rendered");
    });
    vent.trigger('app:show', Controller.layout);  <!-- is this needed for each?
};
```

So I have that code in each of my controllers.  The StartLayout has two regions that have their own views that are the entry points to the InspectorController and the PlayerController.

Each of those controllers has:

```
vent.trigger('app:show', Controller.layout);
```

So it would seem to me that I may be calling 'app:show' more than needed. Once for every Controller that needs initializing.

Is this necessary? I can understand perhaps calling that when I'm dealing with direct child views of the app but if I'm deep into PlayerController and the app view isn't visible it seems like overkill.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to think of "calling" app:show. It's not a function, it's an event. An event can have an arbitrary number of subscriptions listening for it. In the case of this application, there is only one listener on that event:

```
vent.on('app:show', function(appView) {
  app.content.show(appView);
});
```

In this case, it's telling the `content` region to display whatever view is included in the event as `appView`. So, if you want to replace the `content` region with your own view, you should trigger `app:show` with a parameter of whatever view you want the `content` region to display.

`content` is bound to a DOM element, and whenever you call `content.show(someView)`, the contents of that DOM element will be replaced by whatever is generated by `someView.render().el`.

I would suggest reading up on [Layouts](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md), [Regions](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md), and [Events](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr#basic-use).

Hope this helps.